# Building audio programs

Tags: makefile

I'm on Windows. I’ve been having this problem for months. Maybe I don’t understand the difference between including and linking. I’m overwhelmed by the number of files provided in the Portaudio directory, and sub-directories after auto-building.  I want to be able to build any project using Portaudio, hopefully without relying on an IDE. I want to build the example programs to get used to the build process, and not so much the coding itself. What do I need to do to make this happen? Can I simply include the Portaudio header file, or do I need to build a binary library from the source files, and link to it? Either way I would like to use a Makefile to accomplish these tasks. How would I want to edit my provided Makefile to accomplish either of these tasks?

Makefile

```
    CC=gcc 

    Include= -Iinclude/portaudio.h 
    pink: paex_pink.c $(Include)
        $(CC) -o pink paex_pink.c
```

Comment: This is too big for anybody to look at it. Zero down on the problem and present the smallest possible reproducible example of your problem. It is your responsibility to narrow down the problem until you can't narrow down any more and you still don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the last question is that you should have

```
Include := include/portaudio.h
```

"no rule to make target" means Make does not know how to make `-Iinclude/portaudio.h`

for the other questions, they are too vague and your example too big.

The proper procedure is, that you must show effort before asking question. "Effort" means,  precisely state what the expected behaviour is, and what different behaviour you get. Show what you tried to do, and prepare the smallest possible reproducible example of your problem.